# What's wrong with this angular.js form?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ajaxform

I'm having trouble with this simple form:  My lack of javascript is holding me back!

If anyone can give me some pointers: I have been unable to find documentation (non-php), which I understand, and gives a full overview of connecting the form data to the '$http' service.

(I'm not getting errors however the data is not registering with the server.)

data format:

```
    {"item_name":"Contact Me Form", "item_data":{"Name":"John Smith", "Email":"john@smith.com", "PhoneNumber":"222-333-4444"}}
```

script:

```
angular.module('formApp', [])
.controller('FormController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.form_data = {};

  $scope.update = function(user) {
    $scope.form_data = angular.copy(user);
     var dataObject = {
    item_name : "Contact Me Form"
    ,item_data : $scope.form_data
   };

 var responsePromise = $http.post("http://server-url", dataObject, {});
               responsePromise.success(function(dataFromServer, status, headers, config)                
               {
                   var outputDate=angular.fromJson(dataFromServer);
               });
                responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log("Error in fetching user store call!");
               });    
            };
        }]);


           <div ng-app="formApp">
                <div ng-controller="FormController">
                    <form novalidate class="animated" >
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            ng-model="user.Name"
                            class="form-control" 
                            id="Name" 
                            placeholder="Your Name" required /><br />
                        <input 
                            type="email" 
                            ng-model="user.Email" 
                            class="form-control " 
                            id="Email" 
                            placeholder="Company Email" required/><br />
                        <input 
                            type="text" ng-model="user.PhoneNumber"
                            class="form-control  "
                            id="Number"
                            placeholder="Phone - (optional)" /><br />
                        <input 
                            id="submit"
                            class="btn-default btn-lg " type="submit" 
                            ng-click="update(user)" 
                            value="Save"
                            />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Where are you calling your http post function?

Comment: I don't see a user object in your scope. So I would assume that form_data is undefined. Maybe initialize it to {}? $scope.user = {};

Comment: No errors from the console